# How to use environment in scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I am learning scheme in an university and get confused about the environment in scheme. If I understanding correctly it can be used to distinguish variables while they are in different environment.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778849/create-environment-with-variables-in-scheme), `(define env (variable 'x 10 env))` defines variable x and its value into `env`. The question is what `env` actually is? Is it a list or a datum or a string?

How do you define an initia environment that is empty?

Comment: It's whatever the `variable` function returns.

Comment: You can see what it is in the other question. `variable` calls `cons` to create an association list.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. Is it just a list of defined variables with its value?

Comment: The second answer in that question shows multiple possible implementations. One is just a list, another implements it as a closure, another as a hash table. It doesn't really matter, as long as `get-value` knows how to look up a value in it.

Comment: This is an example of an *abstract data type*. It doesn't matter how it's implemented, only that it implements a particular interface.

Comment: see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851869/849891) helps.

Comment: what is a dog, really? does it really matter, as long as it barks and wags its tail?

Comment: In the link you have in your question I have [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48798011/1565698) where I mention several ways I've seen it done. In all of them I have `the-empty-environment` defined so can look at that.